# Menu vertical escondido con tres rayitas

Tags: css

tengo actualmente un menu horizontal arriba en la pagina y al hacer click varia el contenido abajo obviamente.
Pero quiero crear un menu vertical a la izquierda porque me parece mas comodo para dispositivos moviles, y quiero que tenga las 3 rayitas el logo standar que lo haga aparecer y desaparecer.
alguien tiene algun tutorial o codigo de ejemplo?

```html
<ul class="sidebar">
    <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>ABM</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Cliente</span>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=articulo&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><span>Articulo</span>
        </a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=marca&action=index">Marca</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=categoria&action=index">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=subcategoria&action=index">SubCategoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=proveedor&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Proveedores</span></a></a></li>
       <!--  <li ><a href="index.php?controller=envase&action=todos">Envases</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=medida&action=index">Medidas</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=canilla&action=index">Canillas</a></li> --!>
       <li ><a href="index.php?controller=user&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Usuarios</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Tengo ese menu de arriba.
Actualmente tengo en el index principal el modelo vista controlador, es decir la funcion call incluye el archivo html de la vista que se llama:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>GESTION</title>
 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylos.css"/>
   
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylos.css" />
        <script src="includes/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
       
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>


        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="views/login.js"></script>
    

      <?php       
        require_once("routes.php");
      
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) ){



    if (isset($_GET['controller'])&&isset($_GET['action'])) {
 require_once("views/template.php");
        $controller=$_GET['controller'];

        $action=$_GET['action'];
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            call($controller,$action,$id);
        }else{
            
        call($controller,$action,0); }

    }else{
        
    } 
}

else{
    echo '<div class="contenedor">
<div class="cabecera">
</div>
<div class="cuerpo">
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:50%">
<div class="panel-heading">INGRESE AL SISTEMA</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label style="color: blue">Usuario:</label></div><div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" style="color:blue" name="login_username" id="login_username" /></div>
           
          </div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">
                <label style="color: blue">Contraseña:</label></div><div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="password" name="login_userpass" id="login_userpass" style="color:blue" />
        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">
             <span class="timer" id="timer"></span><button id="login_userbttn" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button></div>
              </div>   </div>
</div>
  ';
}
?>
         
   </body>     
</html>
```

Es decir para que el menu sea vertical que debo hacer y para incluir la vista en toda la panatalla y esconder el menu?

Gracias

Comment: Hay varios tutos en google, solo debes encontrar el que te guste, este por ejemplo usa boostrap 4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUmdmCx1RaQ

Comment: Gracias amigo..eso queria.

Comment: Como te han dicho usa bootstrap, mira la version 3.7 y la 4.1 a ver cual te convence más, yo personalmente de momento me quedo en la 3.7 por el tema de los glyphicons sobretodo, además de que es más antiguo y lo conozco mucho mejor.

Comment: Ya encontre un ejemplo..lo estoy queriendo implementar..muchas gracias